# Is $hh^T$ positive semi-definite ($h$ is a column non-negative vector)?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Is $hh^T$ positive semi-definite? It seems to be positive semi-definite, but I cannot prove it. Please help:)

Comment: Interesting side-note: when $h$ is a unit vector, the matrix $hh^T$ represents the orthogonal projection onto $h$. Clearly this is positive semi-definite because $x^T(hh^Tx)$ is $x$ dotted with its projection, and that is always non-negative (the angle between the vector and its projection is always acute or right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any vector $v$,
$$v^T (hh^T)v = (v^Th)(h^Tv)=(v^Th)^T(h^Tv) = (h^Tv)(h^Tv) = \left[h^Tv\right]^2 \geq 0,$$
where the second step follows from the fact that the transpose of a scalar is that same scalar.

Comment: I just think it through using the same comment. Thanks:)